# How can I hide a file from the browser, yet still use it on the webserver with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, vagrant

Here's my scenario:

I have a vagrant cloud set up at an IAAS provider.  It uses a .json file as its catalog to direct download requests from vagrant over to their corresponding .box files on the server.

My goal is to hide the .json file from the browser so that a surfer cannot hit it directly at, say: http://example.com/catalog.json and see the json output as that output lists the url of the box file itself.  However, I still need vagrant to be able to download and use the file so it can grab the box.

In the NGINX docs, it mentions the "internal" directive which seems to offer what I want to do via try_files, but I think I'm either mis-interpreting what it does or just plain doing it wrong. Here's what I'm working with as an example:

First, I have two sub-domains.

One for the .json catalog at: catalog.example.com
A second for the box files at: boxes.example.com

These are mapped, of course, to respective folders on the server, etc.

With that in mind, in sites-available/site.conf, I have the following server blocks:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name catalog.example.com;
    server_name www.catalog.example.com;
    root /var/www/catalog;

    # Use try_files to trigger internal directive to serve json files
    location / {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Serve json files to scripts only with content type header application/json
    location ~ \.json$ {
        internal;
        add_header Content-Type application/json;
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name boxes.example.com;
    server_name  www.boxes.example.com;
    root /var/www/boxes;

    # Use try_files to trigger internal directive to serve json files
    location / {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # Serve box files to scripts only with content type application/octet-stream
    location ~ \.box$ {
        internal;
        add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;
    }
}
```

The NGINX documentation for the internal directive states:

> Specifies that a given location can only be used for internal requests. For external requests, the client error 404 (Not Found) is returned. Internal requests are the following:
>
> requests redirected by the error_page, index, random_index, and try_files directives;

Based on that, my understanding is that my server blocks grab any path for those sub-domains and then, passing it through try_files, should make that available when called via vagrant, yet hide it from the browser if I hit the catalog or a box url directly.

I can confirm that the files are not accessible from the browser; however, they're also unaccessible to vagrant as well.

Am I mis-understanding internal here?  Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the json to accessible inside the machine when some one does `curl http://127.0.0.1/catalog.json` but you don't want to allow any one outside the box to access it?

Comment: The one thing I'm not clear on is what happens when Vagrant goes out to load the box metadata.  I'm assuming that's an external curl request.  So, if there's a way to make it so the vagrant request is the only one that's allowed...  Does that help at all?

Comment: Post your log file for both 404 when you access from outside and from vagrant box. Make sure to keep the client IP available in the log

Comment: I think this is what you want:

76.94.194.237 - - [20/Aug/2017:06:46:37 +0000] "HEAD /sc/demo-base.json HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Vagrant/1.9.7 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.3.4)"

76.94.194.237 - - [20/Aug/2017:06:46:37 +0000] "GET /sc/demo-base.json HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Vagrant/1.9.7 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.3.4)"

First is directly from the browser, second is via Vagrant up

Comment: The source IP is the same ? `76.94.194.237`

Comment: Yep.  I cleared the log and did two fresh queries.  Looks like each query logs two strings in the access log.  Both methods show the same source IP.  

Browser hits have: 
"GET /sc/base.json HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) ...
"GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) ...

Vagrant up hits have: 
"HEAD /sc/demo-base.json HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Vagrant/1.9.5 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.2.5)"
"GET /sc/demo-base.json HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Vagrant/1.9.5 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.2.5)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152366/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-steve-k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure for the sensitive calls the server listens on localhost only
- Create a tunnel between the machine running vagrant (using an arbitrary port) and your IAAS provider machine (on the web server port, for example).
- Create a user on your IAAS machine who is only allowed to interact with the forwarded web-server port (via sshd_config)

Use details from below

https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding

- Reference the tunneled server using  http://:/path in both your catalog.json url and your box file url
- Use a server block in your NGINX config which listens to the `127.0.0.1:80` only and doesn't use `server_name`. You can even add `default_server` to this so that anything that doesn't match other virtual host will hit this block
- Use two locations in your config with different roots to serve files from /var/www/catalog and /var/www/boxes respectively.
- Set regex locations for your .json and .box files and use a try_files block to accept the $uri or redirect to 444 (so you know it hit your block)
- Deny the `/boxes` and `/catalog` otherwise.

See the below nginx config for example

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www;

    location ~ /(catalog|boxes) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name store.example.com; # I will use an eCommerce platform eventually
    root /var/www/store;
}

server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www;

    location ~ \.json$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =444;i
        add_header Content-Type application/json;
    }

    location ~ \.box$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =444;
        add_header Content-Type octet/stream;
    }

    location ~ /(catalog|boxes) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need here is to change the access level to the file. There is 3 access level (execute, read and write) you can remove the execute access level from your file. On the server consul run the command:

```
chmod 766 your_file_name
```

you can see:
[here](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/file-permissions-reference)
[and here](https://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4124/) 
for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what's needed.  If I make the .json file 766, it doesn't stop a user from hitting the .json URL directly in the browser and reading its contents.